# Elegant way to implement repetition block in C#

Tags: c#, loops

A common pattern in coding is to use a iteration variable to do something certain number of times. In many cases, the iteration variable is only used as loop termination condition but adds several lines of code for the purpose.

Example,

```
int counter=100;
while ( counter > 0)
{
//Do something
counter--;
}
```

Does the .NET framework provide a way to define a coding block (Do something in example) and then execute it a given number of times, thereby removing the condition checking and decrementing statements above. This is to reduce the number of visible statements.

Edit: I am looking for way to reduce the number of codes, not make the underlying call efficient.

Comment: That would be the `for(..){..}` statement.

Comment: `for each` + `lambda functions`?

Comment: The `for` loop in C#. The .net runtime will typically unroll simple loops, meaning that there is quite a bit less comparisons in reality, speeding up the loop slightly.

Comment: There's approximately a 0% chance that the condition check and decrement is a performance problem in your code, you almost certainly have better things to spend your time on, if you actually have performance problems in the first place.

Comment: Please define "elegant."

Comment: @Servy Actually I was looking into reducing the statements and not performance.

Comment: Looks like this question is a duplicate, sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in .NET Framework to do something N times without keeping track of number of times you already did something.

But you can write your own extension which will hide all this stuff. E.g.

```
public static void Times(this int count, Action action)
{
   if (count < 0)
      throw new ArgumentException(nameof(count));

   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      action();
}
```

Usage:

```
100.Times(() => Console.WriteLine("hello"))
```

Note that if you'll extract the code which you want to repeat into method which matches `Action` signature, then the code above becomes cleaner:

```
100.Times(DoSomething);
```

Comment: @flaZer: That's provided by the (Sergey) library function, not something the end programmer has to write.  So it does answer the question.  OP didn't suggest that decrementing and condition checking wouldn't be necessary, just that he didn't want to write it for every loop.

Comment: As per another post, the way I want it can't be exactly done, but this is closest to an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3):

whats wrong with

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < limit; counter++)
{
//Do something
}
```

its an instantly recognizable idiom

Comment: You still have a "decrementing statement" and "condition checking"

Comment: @flaZer: And? You can unroll the loop yourself, or let the .net runtime unroll it.

Comment: @flaZer: Well, OP *did* complain about "adds several lines of code for the purpose", which this saves.

Comment: I don't recall OP complaining, nor asking to lighten his code - but instead asking if it were possible to do something, which its seems it's not.

Comment: hmm but variable declaration and intialization is still here `int counter = 0` and counter increment also here `counter++` as well as condition validation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Enumerable.Repeat` to do the trick, not sure if it's really what you thought of elegance

Edit :

Little example how you can generate 100 *different* random values with this method. With a little adaptation it could suit your need

```
var ran = new Random();  
var results = Enumerable.Repeat<Func<int>>(ran.Next, 100)
    .Select(f => f())
    .ToArray();
```

Edit:
I thought you could make it on your own, but some people need clarifications :

```
Enumerable.Repeat(100, () =>
{
    // Do what you want
});
```

Source (for more details):

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/05/03/c.net-little-wonders-the-enumerable.repeat-static-method.aspx

Comment: It's `Enumerable.Repeat` not `IEnumerable.Repeat`, but also it repeats an *object* in a sequence, it doesn't repeatedly perform an action, as is being asked about here.

Comment: I edited my answer, you may have a look again (was on my phone, kinda hard to write a complete answer, i've shouldn't)

Comment: So you've edited your answer to have it perform a whole bunch of entirely unnecessary work (there is no need for random numbers, or to create an array) and *still* aren't doing what the question asks, namely executing some code a given number of times, instead you're creating a given number of objects.  That's not what the question asks for.

Comment: Man, can you just try to understand ? 

The example of code is just to show how you can draw 100 random values. You can replace the `ran.Next` call by anything you want. Did you even read the article I linked ?

Comment: Edited. Can you admitted my answer is true, and leave me alone, now ?

Comment: Your code *isn't* drawing 100 random values, it's creating an array with 100 random values, not performing an operation 100 times.  The two are different things.  Your edit is no different, the code in your lambda needs to produce a value, not perform an operation.  The two aren't the same thing.

Comment: My code is executing the lambda 100 times. If you still not convinced, try yourself, but stop bothering me.

My lambda can produce any value, `void`included. So it's a trick to perform an action 100 times.

Comment: Your edited statement just doesn't compile.  `Enumerable.Repeat` doesn't take a lambda as a second argument (or even the first, for that matter).  Your first snippet wouldn't compile if you provided a void returning method group.  So no, it *doesn't* do that.  If you don't want to be bothered, don't provide an incorrect answer.